# MIME checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, html, mime, file-link

I have linked all Javascript files like this with HTML and all that is working, but when I started linking file 25, it is not getting linked and error is telling MIME checking is enabled. I tried everything but nothing is happening.

Please give me a solution for fix this and above image is the error of my code.

Comment: I cannot imagine what you are referring to.. hard to understand your question for me. Can you please provide some code block or screenshot to make easy to understand your question and the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. No image and no code present